# How to change order state from external file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, order-status, object-manager

Try to change the order state from a file within the Magento root directory.

What I did:

1. Connected to Magento engine and included the object manager:

```
    // Start Magento engine
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php'; 
    $params = $_SERVER;
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
```

2. I already get the order ID from database.
3. Now I try to change order state:

```
     $order = $obj->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order') ->load($orderId);
     $orderState = Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
     $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
     $order->save();
```

But this throws error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Order' not found in [FILE]:633 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [FILE] on line 633
```

I tried and searched, but had no luck. Thanks for any help!

Comment: which error ?????

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Order' not found in [FILE]:633 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in [FILE] on line 633

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :-**

```
$order = $obj->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$order->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING)
      ->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
$order->save();
```